# SSRS formula gives error first function with iif condition gives error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Hello I need to give formula which multiplication of textbox148 & project cost Also i need to select project only for light user.I ave added below formula but it gives error

```
=ReportItems!Textbox148.value
*First(Fields!projectcost_per_Year.Value
(IIf(Fields!Light_user.Value="Yes",1,Nothing), "SAP"),"SAP")
```

Comment: Does the SAP dataset have `projectcost` and `Light_user` fields? Note if you use `First()` function it will return the first row of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to do calculation, you should convert this ReportItems!Textbox148.value to int/double/float etc.
2. (IIf(Fields!Light_user.Value="Yes",1,**0**), "SAP"),"SAP"), i guess the "Nothing" should be "0" to complete calculation.